# Sentence significance score and word frequency distribution stanford-nlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford-nlp to analyse news articles.

I need to compute the word frequency distribution to determine the importance of a word in an article so that I can compute the sentence significance scores based on word importance/frequency.

I've calculated word frequency in the article by using a HashMap but I want to know whether there is anything in stanford-nlp that performs the computation of word significance and sentence significance?

All I could find on the subject was this document:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/intro/fsnlp-slides-ch1.pdf

Is there anything in Stanford CoreNLP that can perform this sentence significance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no tool in the Stanford CoreNLP that does such an analysis for you.

Your implementation using a HashMap seems to be a possible solution. I assume that you count the frequency of every single word in the articles that you're analyzing. I don't know exactly how you are computing the significance but you might want to determine multi-word terms and count their frequency. There is a great paper on the subject of finding such mutli-word terms, which you can find [here](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/sophia.ananiadou/ijodl2000.pdf).

Comment: Yes I'm counting every single word in the article and then storing the frequency in the HashMap. I haven't yet worked out how to compute significance, wanted to check there wasn't anything in Stanford-nlp before I build something, thanks anyway!